# Cucumber : How to print/get all the executed scenario count with status like "Execution Report - Total: 5, passed: 4, failed: 1"

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

I am counting the scenario in After do

```
After do |scenario|
    if scenario.status.to_s=="passed"
      $passed=$passed+1
    elsif scenario.status.to_s=="failed"
      $failed=$failed+1
    end
    $scenario_count=$scenario_count+1
  end
  @browser.close
end
```

In at exit it is like

```
at_exit do |scenario|

 puts  "Execution Report - Total: #{$scenario_count}, passed: #{$passed}, failed: #{$failed}"

end
```

But I am getting

> Execution Report - Total:1 , passed:1 , failed:

Is there anyway to get the count of all executed scenario , as I need to use this in email. It only returns the result of last scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It works with initializing the variable value out of the method

```
$passed=0
$failed=0
$scenario_count=0

After do |scenario|
    if scenario.status.to_s=="passed"
      $passed=$passed+1
    elsif scenario.status.to_s=="failed"
      $failed=$failed+1
    end
    $scenario_count=$scenario_count+1
  end
  @browser.close
end
```

Comment: Make sure you added them in Before hook, so that it will be cleaner.